# R - Find intersect of common elements in two character strings

Tags: r, performance, data.table, mapply

I am looking for the fastest possible way of counting the common elements in two character strings.

The elements in the strings are separated by a `|`.

## Mock data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(input1 = c("A|B", "C|D|", "R|S|T", "A|B"),
                 input2 = c("A|B|C|D|E|F", "C|D|E|F|G", "R|S|T", "X|Y|Z"))
```

Count he common elements in character strings and create `dt$outcome`.

```
dt <- transform(dt, var1 = I(strsplit(as.character(input1), "\\|")))
dt <- transform(dt, var2 = I(strsplit(as.character(input2), "\\|")))
dt <- transform(dt, outcome = mapply(function(x, y) sum(x%in%y),
                                 var1, var2))
```

## Result:

```
> dt
   input1      input2  var1        var2 outcome
1:    A|B A|B|C|D|E|F   A,B A,B,C,D,E,F       2
2:   C|D|   C|D|E|F|G   C,D   C,D,E,F,G       2
3:  R|S|T       R|S|T R,S,T       R,S,T       3
4:    A|B       X|Y|Z   A,B       X,Y,Z       0
```

This example works great, but the real data has thousands of elements for `input1` and `input2` and has over 200,000 rows. The current code runs therefore for days and can't be put into production.

How can we speed this up?

Columns `dt$var1` and `dt$var2` are not required outputs and can be left out.

Comment: If you are using `data.table` and have issues with a high number of rows, why are you using `transform` which is not using `data.table`'s referential semantics? I'd think you may save some time with `dt[, c("var1", "var2") := .(strsplit(input1, "\\|"), strsplit(input2, "\\|"))][, outcome := mapply(function(a, b) sum(a %in% b), var1, var2)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt[, outcome:= lengths(str_extract_all(input2, sub('[|]$', '',input1)))][]
   input1      input2 outcome
1:    A|B A|B|C|D|E|F       2
2:   C|D|   C|D|E|F|G       2
3:  R|S|T       R|S|T       3
4:    A|B       X|Y|Z       0
```

You could speed up the process by writing the code in either C++, C or Fortran. Lets look how the C++ code will look like:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  std::vector<int> count_intersect(std::vector<std::string> vec1,
               std::vector<std::string> vec2, char split){
  auto  string_split = [=](std::string x) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string sub_string;
    for(auto i: x){
      if(i == split) {
        vec.push_back(sub_string);
        sub_string = "";
      }
      else sub_string+=i;
    }
    if(sub_string.size() > 0)vec.push_back(sub_string);
    return  vec;
  };
  
  auto count = [=](std::string input1, std::string input2){
    std::vector<std::string> in1 = string_split(input1);
    std::vector<std::string> in2 = string_split(input2);
    int total = 0;
    for (auto i: in1) 
      if(std::find(in2.begin(), in2.end(), i) != in2.end()) total += 1;
    return total;
  };
  std::size_t len1 = vec1.size();
  std::vector<int> result(len1);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i<len1; i++)
    result[i] = count(vec1[i], vec2[i]);
  return result;
}')

 dt[, outcome:=count_intersect(input1, input2, "|")][]
       input1      input2 outcome
    1:    A|B A|B|C|D|E|F       2
    2:   C|D|   C|D|E|F|G       2
    3:  R|S|T       R|S|T       3
    4:    A|B       X|Y|Z       0
```

Doing the BenchMark: With really large data ie 200,000 rows:

```
bigdt <- mosaic::sample(dt, 200000, TRUE)[,1:2]
inputs <- c("input1", "input2")
vars <- c("var1", "var2")

bench::mark(OP = {
  bigdt <- transform(bigdt, var1 = I(strsplit(as.character(input1), "\\|")))
  bigdt <- transform(bigdt, var2 = I(strsplit(as.character(input2), "\\|")))
  bigdt <- transform(bigdt, outcome = mapply(function(x, y) sum(x%in%y), var1, var2))
},
r2evans = {
  bigdt[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, strsplit, "|", fixed = TRUE), .SDcols = inputs
  ][, outcome := mapply(function(x, y) sum(x %in% y), var1, var2)]
},
r2evans2 = {bigdt[, outcome := mapply(function(x, y) sum(x %in% y), 
                          strsplit(input1, "|", fixed = TRUE), 
                          strsplit(input2, "|", fixed = TRUE)) ]},
onyambu = {
  bigdt[, outcome:= lengths(stringr::str_extract_all(input2, sub('[|]$', '',input1)))]
},
onyambuCpp = bigdt[, outcome:=count_intersect(input1, input2, "|")],
 relative = TRUE
)



 A tibble: 5 x 13
  expression   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                     memory     time       gc      
  <bch:expr> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                     <list>     <list>     <list>  
1 OP         12.4   12.1       1        30.9       Inf     1     6      1.66s <data.table [200,000 x 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
2 r2evans     4.77   4.66      2.60      5.72      Inf     1     3   641.39ms <data.table [200,000 x 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
3 r2evans2    6.08   5.94      2.04      5.70      Inf     1     5    817.4ms <data.table [200,000 x 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
4 onyambu     7.36   7.20      1.68      2.47      NaN     1     0   990.19ms <data.table [200,000 x 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
5 onyambuCpp  1      1        12.1       1         NaN     4     0   549.54ms <data.table [200,000 x 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

Note that the the unit is relative, and CPP atleast 4* faster than the next method.

Comment: I concede to your double+ speed :-)

Comment: @r2evans haha. Thats okay. Just curios would you know as to why when the data increases, your 2nd code becomes less fast than the first code? Also my first code is comparative to your second code

Comment: It's likely a consequence of benchmarking with `n_itr=1`. I don't expect my two implementations to produce significantly different timings, since most of the time and effort is in the splitting and membership, not in the storage of the split-list; the fact that I saw a slight increase with `n_itr>=23` supports the premise that mid-state storage might have some impact, but the `\`itr/sec\``s were close enough to be mostly comparable. More testing would inform well, but admittedly (1) your cpp is much faster for this bespoke problem, and (2) I think I'm out of time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Two things that should help:

1. Use `data.table`'s referential semantics, intended specifically for efficiency/speed. Your use of `transform` is slowing you down a lot:

   ```r
   bench::mark(
     base = { bigdt <- transform(bigdt, var1 = I(strsplit(as.character(input1), "\\|"))); },
     datatable = { bigdt[, var1 := strsplit(input1, "\\|")]; }
   )
   # # A tibble: 2 x 13
   #   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                   memory   time    gc    
   #   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                   <list>   <list>  <list>
   # 1 base         2.69ms   3.44ms     271.      299KB     0      136     0      501ms <data.table [4,000 x 3]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
   # 2 datatable   11.33ms  13.53ms      68.0     110KB     2.27    30     1      441ms <data.table [4,000 x 3]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
   ```
2. Shift from `strsplit(., "\\|")` to `strsplit(., "|", fixed = TRUE)` to reduce the overhead of regex.

   ```r
   bench::mark(
     regex = strsplit(bigdt$input1, "\\|"), 
     fixed = strsplit(bigdt$input1, "|", fixed = TRUE)
   )
   # # A tibble: 2 x 13
   #   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result         memory             time    gc    
   #   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>         <list>             <list>  <list>
   # 1 regex        1.94ms   2.12ms      419.    31.3KB     0      210     0      501ms <list [4,000]> <Rprofmem [1 x 3]> <bench~ <tibb~
   # 2 fixed       219.7us 246.95us     3442.    31.3KB     2.21  1554     1      452ms <list [4,000]> <Rprofmem [1 x 3]> <bench~ <tibb~
   ```

(Since many columns often have different units, I tend to look at `` `itr/sec` `` as a reasonable measure of relative performance.)

Combining the two techniques (and including onyambu's excellent recommendation), we see a dramatic improvement:

```r
inputs <- c("input1", "input2")
vars <- c("var1", "var2")
bench::mark(OP = {
  bigdt <- transform(bigdt, var1 = I(strsplit(as.character(input1), "\\|")))
  bigdt <- transform(bigdt, var2 = I(strsplit(as.character(input2), "\\|")))
  bigdt <- transform(bigdt, outcome = mapply(function(x, y) sum(x%in%y), var1, var2))
},
r2evans = {
  bigdt[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, strsplit, "|", fixed = TRUE), .SDcols = inputs
       ][, outcome := mapply(function(x, y) sum(x %in% y), var1, var2)]
},
onyambu = {
  bigdt[, outcome:= lengths(stringr::str_extract_all(input2, sub('[|]$', '',input1)))]
}
)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                   memory   time    gc    
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                   <list>   <list>  <list>
# 1 OP           18.8ms  20.95ms      43.7    1.21MB     2.30    19     1      435ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
# 2 r2evans       7.5ms   8.42ms     105.   238.19KB     2.28    46     1      439ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
# 3 onyambu      10.9ms  11.87ms      80.8  130.36KB     0       41     0      508ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
```

This scales consistently. If I use a similarly larger table, perhaps

```r
bench::mark(...)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                     memory   time   gc   
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                     <list>   <list> <lis>
# 1 OP            2.71s    2.71s     0.369   96.56MB     2.21     1     6      2.71s <data.table [400,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <benc~ <tib~
# 2 r2evans       1.38s    1.38s     0.723    17.8MB     2.17     1     3      1.38s <data.table [400,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <benc~ <tib~
# 3 onyambu       1.53s    1.53s     0.652    7.66MB     0        1     0      1.53s <data.table [400,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <benc~ <tib~
```

While only one iteration, both of the suggested answers have significant speed improvements over the base-case.

We can improve even a little more if we adapt onyambu's choice to *not* save intermediate `var1` and `var2` values, with:

```r
# r2evans_2
bigdt[, outcome := mapply(function(x, y) sum(x %in% y), 
                          strsplit(input1, "|", fixed = TRUE), 
                          strsplit(input2, "|", fixed = TRUE)) ]
bench::mark(...)
# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                   memory   time    gc    
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                   <list>   <list>  <list>
# 1 OP          18.27ms  18.85ms      52.7    1.21MB   190.       5    18     94.9ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
# 2 r2evans      7.28ms   8.18ms     123.   241.09KB   133.      24    26    195.7ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
# 3 r2evans_2    6.61ms   7.56ms     134.   205.57KB   105.      33    26      247ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
# 4 onyambu      10.7ms  12.21ms      82.8  110.88KB     2.02    41     1    495.2ms <data.table [4,000 x 5]> <Rprofm~ <bench~ <tibb~
```

A trick with code-optimization problems like this is to whittle from big problems down to smaller ones. I think this is a good start. If you need faster, you might need to shift to compiled or a different language, I don't know (offhand) how this can be improved much.

---

Data, bigger than your 4 rows:

```r
bigdt <- rbindlist(replicate(1000, dt, simplify=FALSE))
biggerdt <- rbindlist(replicate(100000, dt, simplify=FALSE))
```